# Zipping unequal length lists in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-collections, zipper

I want something like this:

`def unequalZip[A, B](a: Iterable[A], b: Iterable[B]) = Iterable[(Option[A], Option[B])]`

where the items from the shorter iterable is matched with items from longer iterable using `None`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`def lift[A](a: Iterable[A]) = a map {Option.apply}
def unequalZip[A, B](a: Iterable[A], b: Iterable[B]) = lift(a).zipAll(lift(b), None, None)`

Answer (score 8):

You want

```
a.zipAll(b, None, None)
```

if you already have options, or

```
a.map(x => Option(x)).zipAll(b.map(x => Option(x)), None, None)
```

otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at zipAll.

> /** Returns a $coll formed from this $coll and another iterable
>   collection    *  by combining corresponding elements in pairs.    * 
>   If one of the two collections is shorter than the other,    * 
>   placeholder elements are used to extend the shorter collection to the
>   length of the longer.